# Emploi du mot « misconception »

Tags: anglais, usage, anglicismes

> Enlever la « misconception » des étudiants que les solutions aux problèmes en mécanique sont un méli-mélo de cas particuliers.

Le mot *misconception* n'existe pas dans les dictionnaires que j'ai consultés. Ce [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=misconception&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmisconception%3B%2Cc0) montre que le mot est employé en français. Est-il fiable ? Dans ce contexte quel tournure rend mieux l'idée de misconception ? *Idée fausse, mauvaise compréhension, méprise* ?

Comment: Je ne vois que des faux positifs. Où as tu vu des occurrences suspectes ?

Comment: Si le mot avait existé, ç'aurait peut-être été « *méconception* » ou « *malconception* » , comme *miscreant* / mécréant, *mistake* / méprise, *misalliance* / mésalliance, *misunderstanding* / malentendu, etc., mais il n'existe pas...

Comment: Le paramètre "smoothing" de Ngram est trompeur, il donne l'impression que l'utilisation est relativement constante et répandue. [Voilà](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=misconception&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmisconception%3B%2Cc0) la même recherche sans lissage. On voit mieux des usages ponctuels.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Le lissage n'est pas tellement à remettre en cause. Une méthode efficace pour éviter ce type d'écueils est de placer le mot dans un contexte. Il suffit de mettre un article (*la* ou *une*) avant le mot recherché et on voit tout de suite que Google Trends ne trouve plus d'occurrences. Une autre méthode consiste à demander quels mots précèdent ou suivent le mot recherché (" * misconception" ou "misconception * ") et en retour, on voit que seuls *a* et *the* précèdent et que seuls *of* et *that* suivent, signalant clairement la langue véritablement utilisée.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Larousse en ligne](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/misconception/595528) dit **mauvaise compréhension** pour *poor understanding* et **idée fausse, méprise** pour *complete misunderstanding* avec dans ce dernier cas l'exemple *a popular misconception* « une fausse idée couramment répandue ». [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/misconception) parle d'une **idée erronée** ; voir aussi [Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=misconception&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) pour des emplois spécifiques. En contexte on avisera selon qu'on estime que les étudiants comprennent mal ou pas du tout...

Answer (score 2):

Personnellement, je n'ai jamais entendu  « misconception ».

D'après ce que je comprends, j'utiliserai la phrase :

> Corriger la mauvaise compréhension des étudiants ...

Ou bien, en modifiant complètement :

> Les étudiants doivent se rendre compte (réaliser/prendre conscience) que les solutions ne sont pas qu'un méli-mélo (agrégat/ensemble) de cas particuliers.

Comment: « Idée fausse » me parait mieux dans cette phrase.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: Oui, mais la phrase devient « l'idée fausse des étudiants que les solutions ... », ce n'est pas vraiment satisfaisant. À vrai dire c'est la tournure de phrase dans son ensemble qui est à revoir mais je n'arrive pas à trouver une formulation claire.

Comment: Ah, oui bien sûr, il faut reformuler. Quelque chose comme « L'idée fausse des étudiants selon laquelle les blabla seraient blabla » ferait surement l'affaire. Ta deuxième proposition me parait bien aussi.

Answer (score 1):

En anglais le nom « misconception » signifie « une  conviction ou une idée qui n'est pas fondée sur de l'information correcte ou qui n'est pas comprise par les gens.

En français il y a les concepts « **idée préconçue** » et « **idée reçue** » qui ont des significations se rapportant beaucoup à l'idée de ce qu'est la « misconception » mais qui ajoutent une modalité les rendant des traductions non précises.

> (TLFi) Idée préconçue
>   a) Cour., souvent péj. Idée qui est admise d'avance, sans avoir été mise à l'épreuve et sans critique suffisante. Synon. préjugé, prévention. Pour y parvenir [à saisir ce qui lui apparaît comme étant la réalité], il s'acharne [l'auteur réaliste] à débarrasser ce qu'il observe de toute la gangue d'idées préconçues et d'images toutes faites qui l'enveloppent, de toute cette réalité de surface que tout le monde perçoit sans effort et donc chacun se sert, faute de mieux (SARRAUTE, Ère soupçon, 1956, p.141).

> (TLFi) Idée(s) reçue(s). Idée(s) toute(s) faite(s); préjugé(s). En aura-t-on fini avec la métaphysique creuse et les idées reçues? Tout le mal vient de notre gigantesque ignorance. Ce qui devrait être étudié est cru sans discussion. Au lieu de regarder, on affirme! (FLAUB., Dict. des idées reçues, Lettre à G. Sand, Paris, Aubier Montaigne, 1978 [1871], p. 10).Fin de l'objet 1 de la requête (Paragraphe)

L'idée préconçue n'est pas nécessairement fausse (*souvent péjoratif*, seulement) et l'idée reçue est un terme qui nous dit comment l'idée s'est matérialisée, ce que ne fait pas le terme « misconception » ; encore une fois, la notion d'idée reçue n'est pas celle d'un concept nécessairement positif ; il suffit pour se rendre compte de cela de consulter le *[Dictionnaire des idées reçues](http://www.leboucher.com/pdf/flaubert/b_fla_di.pdf)*, écrit par Flaubert.

Donc, ce mot anglais, « misconception », dont la forme n'existe pas en français, semble n'avoir aucun équivalent exact dans le langage ; on voit qu'il est formé avec le préfixe « mis- », qui n'est pas autre chose que le préfixe français « mé- », aussi « més- » pour les besoins de l'euphonie, et du mot « conception », dont la forme en français signifie la même chose.

> (TLFi) MÉ-, MES-, MÉS-, préf.
>   Préf. issu de la particule francique missi (ou moins vraisemblablement du lat. minus), servant à construire les formes négatives ou péj. de verbes et plus rarement de subst. et d'adj.

Si l'on consulte la liste des mots français construits avec ce préfixe on s'aperçoit que l'on a un système de production assez libre (liste essentiellement complète ci-dessous);

*mécompte
mécompter
méconduire
méconduite
méconnaissable
méconnaissance
méconnaitre
méconnue
mécontente
mécontentement
mécontenter
mécontentée
mécroire
mécréance
mécréante
médire
médisance
médisante
méfait
méfiance
méfiante
méfier
méforme
méplat
méprendre
mépris
méprisable
méprisante
méprise
mépriser
mévendre
mévente*

*mésalliance
mésappariement
mésaventure
mésentente
mésestimation
mésestime
mésintelligence
mésinterprétation
mésusage*

Il me semble que le cas est tout indiqué pour la création d'un néologisme, « **méconception** », réservée à qui voudra bien être l'initiateur de ce nouvel usage.

Une paraphrase assez fidèle serait « **idées reçues ou préconçues erronées** ».

Comment: Dans un commentaire à la question, j'ai déjà parlé de *méconception* en signalant que le mot n'existait pas. Une petite recherche montre cependant que ce n'est pas vraiment le cas. Je trouve pas mal d'occurrences récentes, mais j'en vois aussi une dans un ouvrage de 1830 (Annales de la  médecine physiologique, F J V Broussais). On ne peut plus vraiment parler de néologisme mais plutôt d'un mot passé sous le radar des lexicographes.

Comment: @jlliagre J'ai vu cela après avoir répondu, comme il m'arrive assez souvent de faire une réponse sans consulter le travail en cours. Oui, je vois, la situation est la même que pour le mot « minuende » ; on le trouve sous la plume du mathématicien Elie Ritter mais dans aucun dictionnaire ; quoi qu'il en soit, néologisme ou remise en vogue compte tenu d'une révision des standards de discrimination des lexicographes, la traduction assez fréquente du terme anglais et l'importance du concept elle-même justifient que cette forme ou une autre, similaire, soit introduite assez formellement.

Comment: @Survenant9r7  Le mot est utilisé en France en 1830, à une époque où les anglicismes ne sont pas légion. Je trouve aussi: *Ces idées préconçues ou fausses idées seront principalement nommées, dans cet article, par le terme de
« méconception ». Sans être un anglicisme à proprement parler, nous souhaitons faire une analogie entre le terme de méconception et le terme de misconception. En effet, à notre connaissance et sans rentrer dans un débat linguistique, il n’existe aucun terme français qui ne saurait traduire mieux nos propos et ce sans être assimilé à des idées dogmatiques ou autres.*

Comment: @Survenant9r7 https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01532068/document

Comment: @Survenant9r7 *Je liens à le répéter, votre méconception du rôle et des possibilités de Genève a eu ce double résultat : regrouper plus fortement que jamais nos ennemis; dissocier nos alliés pour partie.*, 1933, Journal officiel de la République française. Débats parlementaires. Chambre des députés, p. 4115.

Comment: @jlliagre dit un professeur d'anglais né au Royaume-Uni (Jersey). Ces deux exemples, quoique d'emplois recherchés contrairement à ceux qui dominent les résultats en tête du moteur de recherche, demeurent anecdotiques et ne font que confirmer mon opinion à l'effet que l'emploi de ce terme est anglicisant et dépend de repères entièrement construits sur ceux de la langue anglaise, repères que je rejette sans réserve, mon seul regret étant de ne pouvoir désapprendre cette langue-là pour ne pas les y apercevoir détourner ma langue de son cours naturel et brouiller constamment sa limpidité.

Comment: @jlliagre J'observe que _conception_ pour l'_idée_ c'est par métonymie de la faculté de concevoir, ce qui est moins clair que l'épithète appliqué au nom. Je note que le préfixe n'est plus productif. Je lis des exemples tels _Je fait souvent face à une méconception de mon trouble_, c'est _mauvaise compréhension_ ou _méconnaissance_ qui va là... la personne qui rédige pense en anglais en formulant. Ailleurs : _La méconception ici vient du fait qu'on voit bien la Lune bouger_... c'est _erreur_ qui va là. Et j'en passe. Je ne reconnais l'empreinte du français ni dans ce mot ni dans son emploi...

Comment: @Survenant9r7 Que va-t-on dire du mot « médire » alors, et d'autres ?

Comment: @Survenant9r7 Il n'est pas question de changer « méfait » en « malfait », auquel, de toute façon on peut donner deux significations sur le plan que l'on choisit, soit le plan moral soit le plan de la méthode ; il en va de même pour des quantités de formations de mots par préfixation ; on ne peut pas mettre  les uns en cause en sanctifiant les autres.

Comment: @Survenant9r7 *...dépend de repères entièrement construits sur ceux de la langue anglaise, repères que je rejette sans réserve, mon seul regret étant de ne pouvoir désapprendre cette langue-là pour ne pas les y apercevoir détourner ma langue de son cours naturel et brouiller constamment sa limpidité.* Heureusement que les anglophones ne rejettent pas en bloc tous les mots français ou aux racines françaises (comme *misconception*) qui sont une composante essentielle de leur vocabulaire... ;-)

Comment: @Survenant9r7 I suggest to you to open a chat room and to go on there with this conversation that has nothing to do in the space reserved only to commentaries about the question.