# La « méconception » : sens, origine, utilité ?

Tags: usage, origine-ou-raison, préfixes

Sur internet j'ai recensé [369 emplois](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%22m%C3%A9conception%22) de « [mé](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%A9-)[conception](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/conception) », la majorité *semblant* provenir (je n'ai pas épluché les résultats) de ce millénaire.

- Quel en est le **sens** exact, la définition en français et y a-t-il adéquation entre ce sens et la préfixation utilisée ?
- Peut-on illustrer son **origine** ou un emploi plus ancien intéressant ?
- Peut-on comparer deux exemples où l'on traiterait exactement d'un
  même sens étayé précédemment et où le terme ne
  ferait pas double-emploi avec un des mots/groupes nominaux suivants
  : *mauvaise compréhension, méprise, fausse idée, idée fausse, idée
  préconçue, idée erronée, concept mal formé, méconnaissance, vice de
  raisonnement* ?
- Suivant ce qu'on aura répondu précédemment et à l'exclusion de toute idée de traduction peut-on motiver une opinion sur son **utilité** en français ?

Comment: Au moins 4 (parmi les 8 résultats, 4 faux positifs) attestations [ici](https://gallica.bnf.fr/services/engine/search/sru?operation=searchRetrieve&version=1.2&query=%28gallica%20all%20%22m%C3%A9conception%22%29&lang=en&suggest=0), dont au moins une date de plus d'un siècle.

Answer (score 3):

1. - Quel en est le sens exact, la définition en français et y a-t-il adéquation entre ce sens et la préfixation utilisée ?

Mauvaise conception. Idée fausse car qu'elle s'appuie sur un concept erroné. Point de vue partagé par un nombre significatif de personnes, mais qui ne correspond pas à la réalité.

Le sens de *conception* est le **2.- A.- II.-** du [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/conception) (Résultat de l'action de concevoir). Le préfixe *mé-* (forme négative/péjorative) a la même origine et le même sens que le *mis-* anglais.

2. - Peut-on illustrer son origine ou un emploi plus ancien intéressant ?

La majorité des occurrences est indubitablement le fait de personnes bilingues ou familières avec la langue anglaise, pour lesquelles *méconception* est le pendant naturel de l'anglais *misconception*. Un indice qui va dans ce sens est la surreprésentation d'écrits publiés au Canada francophone.

On peut néanmoins hésiter à attribuer à une influence de l'anglais la première apparition du mot qui date de 1830<sup>1</sup>, par un médecin de Narbonne :

> Le défaut d'alimentation chez les malades a des inconvéniens graves, dont on a observé de nombreux exemples : nous devons dire ici qu'une méconception du principe élémentaire de notre doctrine a pu contribuer à les multiplier.

Une autre utilisation, qui n'occulte pas l'influence de l'anglais, mais qui [justifie l'utilisation en français](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01532068/document) est la suivante :

> Ces idées préconçues ou fausses idées seront principalement nommées, dans cet article, par le terme de « méconception ». Sans être un anglicisme à proprement parler, nous souhaitons faire une analogie entre le terme de méconception et le terme de misconception. En effet, à notre connaissance et sans rentrer dans un débat linguistique, il n’existe aucun terme français qui ne saurait traduire mieux nos propos et ce sans être assimilé à des idées dogmatiques ou autres.

3. - Peut-on comparer deux exemples où l'on traiterait exactement d'un même sens étayé précédemment et où le terme ne ferait pas double-emploi avec un des mots/groupes nominaux suivants : mauvaise compréhension, méprise, fausse idée, idée fausse, idée préconçue, idée erronée, concept mal formé, méconnaissance, vice de raisonnement ?

Non. Le mot *méconception* n'est pas (encore ?) assez répandu pour que l'on puisse trouver une phrase où il aurait déjà pleinement sa place. Voici néanmoins quelques commentaires sur les propositions vis à vis du mot *méconception*.

> mauvaise compréhension :

je perçois une différence entre:
  - je n'arrive pas à le concevoir
  - je n'arrive pas à le comprendre

> méprise :

assez proche, mais il me semble que l'on reconnaîtra plus facilement sa méprise que sa *méconception*.

> fausse idée / idée fausse :

ce sont de bons choix pour éviter *méconception*. La phrase *c'est une méconception très répandue* est tout à fait équivalente à *c'est une idée reçue très répandue*.

> idée préconçue :

Une idée préconçue est très souvent mais pas nécessairement incorrecte. (*conçue avant* est différent *de mal conçue*)

> idée erronée :

Le sens y est mais il manque peut-être le fait qu'elle est souvent partagée par un grand nombre de personnes.

> concept mal formé :

Une méconception n'est pas que mal formée, elle est fausse.

> méconnaissance :

L'un des sens de méconnaître est très proche, mais méconnaissance est le plus souvent utilisé pour dire que l'on ne connait pas quelque chose alors que la *méconception*, c'est penser connaître, mais en se trompant.

> vice de raisonnement :

Ce serait plutôt un *vice de conception* mais l'expression à déjà un sens établi et différent.

4. - Suivant ce qu'on aura répondu précédemment et à l'exclusion de toute idée de traduction peut-on motiver une opinion sur son utilité en français ?

Le préfixe mé- n'est pas aussi improductif qu'il n'y parait. Des mots comme *méforme*, *mécompris* et *mécompréhension* apparus au XX<sup>e</sup> siècle  sont assez vivaces. Ce préfixe est connu et compris grâce à des mots courants comme *méconnu*, *mécontent* ou *mésaventure*.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>On ne trouve pas trace d'utilisations plus anciennes, même en moyen ou ancien français</sub>

Comment: Je viens finalement de lire votre contribution. Je l’avais vue, et en avait ressenti un certain malaise car je travaillais moi-même sur une réponse, et ne voulais pas dupliquer la vôtre ou me rendre coupable de m'en inspirer avant de la proposer en ligne. Au final, je crois que ce sera bien d'avoir deux réponses bien développées. Merci et +1.

Comment: @Montéedelait Bien sûr, +1 :-)

Answer (score 2):

#### La *méconception*, quel sens ?

La *méconception*, en premier lieu, est très possiblement inspiré du terme anglais *misconception*. Il est possible que le français n’y serait pas arrivé par lui-même, attendu que le préfixe *mé-* n’est plus productif, [selon le TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%A9-) :

> **Vitalité** Ce préfixe n’est plus productif aujourd’hui. L’usage courant semble préférer l’emploi de périphrases avec « ne pas, mal » devant un verbe ou « mauvais » devant un substantif. Le préfixe est, par ailleurs, concurrencé par *dé- (méplaire/déplaire)* ou *mal- (malaise/mésaise; malfaire/méfaire)*. Les mots apparus au XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle et surtout au XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle doivent être considérés, à quelques exceptions près *(mécompréhension, méforme, mésemploi)* comme des néologismes ou des hapax.

Pour autant, la sonorité ou la construction ne détonne pas à l’oreille francophone. Si l’on passe outre que le terme n’est pas entré dans les dictionnaires les plus courants de la langue française, et si nous faisons aussi abstraction de son origine possiblement anglaise *(et donc impure ?),* on pourrait facilement justifier de s’y attarder au moins un instant, pour juger de la validité du concept qu’il prétend exprimer, possiblement introduire en langue française.

Qu’est donc la *méconception* ? Elle peut être une **idée fausse**, pouvant résulter de :

- la mésinterprétation de certains résultats ou observations ;
- l’ignorance, volontaire ou non, de certains aspects d’un raisonnement, d’une théorie, d’une situation, de la réalité, etc. ;

La *méconception* n’est pas une **erreur** *(de jugement ou autre)* ou un **vice de raisonnement**, elle est plutôt le résultat de ceux-ci. Elle n’est pas non plus une **mésinterprétation** ou une **mécompréhension**, mais ce qui découlerait de l’une ou l’autre. Dire qu’elle est **méconnaissance** ne fonctionne pas, en ce sens que si l’on peut ignorer tout d’un sujet, jusqu’à son existence même, et pouvoir être accusé à raison de le méconnaître *(un inventeur injustement méconnu est un inconnu pour la majorité, n’est-ce pas ?)*, alors qu’on ne saurait en cas de semblable ignorance affirmer qu’il y a **méconception**.

La *méconception* pourrait aussi inclure le domaine des **conclusions hâtives**, ou initialement conçues pour être **temporaires**, mais n’ayant plus bougé depuis longtemps, faute d’intérêt parfois, ou alors faute de chercher dans la bonne direction pour des contre-exemples, et ayant de ce fait atteint un statut de vérité dans l’esprit d’une personne ou d’un groupe.

Le terme **méconclusion** n’existe pas non plus en français, mais il ne s’appliquerait pas non plus exactement à la *méconception*, laquelle est plus vaste et peut très bien survenir lors d’un l’apprentissage, en un moment où il est fort possible qu’aucune conclusion ne se soit clairement établie dans l’esprit de l’apprenant, en un moment où il tente simplement de tracer son chemin et de trouver des repères dans un monde de savoir nouveau pour lui.

Elle n’est pas forcément non plus le résultat d’une erreur de jugement. Parfois, on peut simplement ne pas connaître certains aspects du problème.

Toutes ces définitions des limites du concept semblent plus ou moins cerner le domaine d’application du terme **méprise**. Je demeure néanmoins sur ma faim. Pourquoi ? Deux motifs :

- Certaines cooccurrences très communes *(grossière, lourde, impardonnable, grave méprise)* donnent à la méprise une couleur assez péjorative, même utilisée seule.
- Sa proximité phonétique avec *mépris*, même effet.

---

#### Remplacement par une périphrase ?

Quant aux périphrases... C’est strictement personnel, mais même si je ne lève pas le moins du monde le nez sur l’art de la périphrase, j’aime à avoir un mot unique que je puisse introduire dans une phrase complexe. Ça évite de rajouter une couche de complexité, ça aide le lecteur à se concentrer sur l’idée à transmettre plutôt que sur la façon d’agencer les concepts invoqués dans la phrase. Un exemple d’un auteur, talentueux du reste, qui aurait probablement aimé apprendre le terme [*palanche*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/palanche), qu’il commence par décrire, ce qui n’est pas mauvais en soi, mais qu’il continue à décrire en plusieurs mots chaque nouvelle fois qu’il en fait mention :

> À ses pieds était un bambou, long d'une toise, supportant à chacune de ses extrémités un panier, dont la double pesanteur faisait, lorsque le bambou était posé par le milieu sur l'épaule du marchand, plier cette longue canne comme un arc.
>
> *[...quelques lignes de texte...]*
>
> [...] portant **son long bambou chargé de paniers** tantôt sur une épaule, tantôt sur l'autre [...]
>
> *[...plusieurs pages de texte...]*
>
> Au bout d'une demi-heure, Georges vit paraître son messager; il portait **sa longue perche de bambou et ses deux paniers**, comme s'il eût fait son commerce en ville; car le prévoyant industriel avait pensé qu'il pouvait, sur sa route, rencontrer quelque amateur de chinoiseries.
>
> *[...plusieurs nouvelles pages de texte...]*
>
> Tandis que Georges questionnait Laïza sur les dispositions de chacun, et établissait avec lui les chances de cette périlleuse entreprise, il aperçut de loin son messager Miko-Miko qui, portant toujours sur son épaule **son bambou et ses paniers**, marchait de son pas habituel et s'avançait vers l'habitation.
>
> <sub>—*Georges*, d’Alexandre Dumas père (rien de moins...)</sub>

Mais bon, on peut penser à des expressions déjà mentionnées :

- **idée fausse**, surtout
- ...mais aussi **idée reçue, erronée, préconçue**

---

En dépit du fait que le concept semblerait raisonnablement pouvoir obtenir le droit d’intégrer la langue, les subtilités introduites sont pour le moins discrètes, et dans la plupart des cas on pourrait déplacer légèrement le point de vue et éviter l’utilisation de *méconception* sans que cela ne cause de problèmes majeurs. Par exemple :

- L’enseignement du système de numération positionnel dès la petite enfance et son omniprésence dans nos vies nourrit **la méconception** que l’invention du zéro n’était qu’une formalité.
- L’enseignement du système de numération positionnel dès la petite enfance et son omniprésence dans nos vies oriente la pensée vers **la conclusion simpliste** que l’invention du zéro n’était qu’une formalité.
- L’enseignement du système de numération positionnel dès la petite enfance et son omniprésence dans nos vies offre un chemin tout tracé vers **l’idée fausse** que l’invention du zéro n’était qu’une formalité.
- L’enseignement du système de numération positionnel dès la petite enfance et son omniprésence dans nos vies peut facilement **masquer le fait** que l’invention du zéro fut une révolution.

Comment: Bien intéressant. La pureté n'est pas ce qui me faisait sourciller [etc.](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/34628/emploi-du-mot-misconception#comment70973_34637), davantage les repères, l'origine m'importe peu pourvu que l'emploi ne repose pas sur la maîtrise de la langue anglaise, sa sémantique, sa syntaxe. Mais c'est seulement une opinion. Par ex. quand on m'avait présenté [ceci](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6428088j/f19.image.r=m%C3%A9conception?rk=21459;2), j'ai vu que Franklin-Bouillon était très versé en anglais, je veux que ma langue tienne d'elle-même toute seule.

Comment: @Survenant9r7 Je me doutais bien que vous n'aviez pas de problème avec les emprunts. Ce n'est cependant pas le cas de tous. Je suis prudent en balisant ma progression et en acceptant de perdre des gens le long de mon parcours.

Answer (score 1):

Première page des résultats sur Google, [une occurrence en 1830](https://books.google.fr/books?id=WxAUAAAAQAAJ&lpg=PA259&ots=66itipCe_O&dq=%22m%C3%A9conception%22&hl=fr&pg=PA259#v=onepage&q=%22m%C3%A9conception%22&f=false).

Pour le reste, rien dans le TFL, rien dans tous les autres dictionnaire du [CNTRL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/m%C3%A9conception), rien dans le Grand Robert, rien dans le grand Larousse, rien dans le [DVLF](https://dvlf.uchicago.edu/mot/m%C3%A9conception) et l'[ARTFL](https://artflsrv03.uchicago.edu/philologic4/publicdicos/query?report=bibliography&head=m%C3%A9conception) de l'université de Chicago, rien dans le [Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=m%C3%A9conception&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs), ni dans [France Terme](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=m%C3%A9conception&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search) ni dans le [dictionnaire de TV5 Monde](https://langue-francaise.tv5monde.com/decouvrir/dictionnaire?mot=m%C3%A9conception).

Je n'ai pas tous mes dictionnaires sous la main, mais quelque chose me dit que nous avons affaire à un vieux calque de l'anglais dont le moins que l'on puisse dire est qu'il n'a pas fait florès...

Il faut dire que le français *méprise* conviendrait aussi bien ([voir Larousse par ex.](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/misconception/595528)), donc à quoi bon s'acharner à parler franglais ?

Comment: Peut-être que le terme a été utilisé quelques fois par le passé et, complètement indépendamment, réinventé aujourd'hui : on trouve beaucoup ce phénomène de calque ou de traduction littérale de l’anglais ces jours-ci.