# "se sentir saisir" vs. "se sentir saisi"

Tags: grammaire, sens

Citant p. 357 des Misérables :

> Cosette se sentait saisir par cette énormité noire de la nature.

Pourquoi Hugo a-t-il écrit "saisir" et non pas "saisie" ? Au début, je le prenais pour une faute typographique mais après recherchant cette formule en ligne, je trouvais encore [cela](http://expositions.bnf.fr/lamer/pedago/voyage/antho/5/05.htm), de Hugo aussi :

> Tout à coup il se sentit saisir le bras.

Si je lisais cette phrase pour la première fois, il me semblerait qu'elle voudrait dire que c'était lui qui saisit un bras d'autrui. Mais apparemment, il sent que cette autre personne le saisit par le bras.

Alors pourquoi l'infinitif qui semble donner la phrase un sens actif ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il en va avec *sentir* comme il en va avec *voir, entendre...* et autres verbes de perception.

Ces verbes peuvent être effectivement suivis d'un verbe qui sera soit :

- à l'infinitif : afin d'**insister sur l'action** elle-même, un processus. (c'est ce qui te donne cette impression de *"sens actif"*)
- soit au participe passé : afin d'insister sur le **résultat de l'action**. Un état.

Au passage, mais c'est une autre histoire, le même genre de construction est possible avec ces verbes utilisés pronominalement au participe passé (s'être senti, s'être vu...)
Il faudra alors faire très attention aux accords.

On notera qu'à l'oral, il peut parfois être difficile de faire la différence entre le participe passé et l'infinitif. Le sens peut alors être difficile à saisir (action en cours ou échue) comme le montrent de façon plaisante les liens proposés par @jlliagre en commentaires.

Comment: +1 http://www.parmotsetparvaux.fr/chron/chron345.html & http://alafortunedumot.blogs.lavoixdunord.fr/archive/2011/10/10/definitivement-l-infinitif.html

Comment: @jlliagre : Succulent! Merci!

Answer (score -7):

Cette construction s'explique selon les principes du semi-auxiliaire ; les semi auxiliaires sont basiquement les [verbes suivants](https://www.lepointdufle.net/ressources_fle/present_auxiliaires.htm) : aller, devoir, faire, falloir, laisser, pouvoir, savoir, venir, vouloir.

Ils sont définis le plus simplement comme sur cette page web : [l'obs](https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/grammaire/les-semi-auxiliaires-149.php).

Cependant, il existe d'autres verbes aussi appelé semi-auxiliaires ([encylopédie libre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbe_semi-auxiliaire#Les_cat%C3%A9gories_de_semi-auxiliaires)). (a)

Le critère pour conclure à l'existence d'un semi auxiliaire est donné [ici](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbe_semi-auxiliaire#Distinction_entre_semi-auxiliaires_et_verbes_suivis_d'un_infinitif_compl%C3%A9ment_d'objet) (encyclopédie libre) : « saisir » ne peut pas être pronominalisé : « Elle se le sentait. » ne convient pas. « Saisir » ne peut pas être complément d'objet.

Si on revient à la classification des semi-auxiliaires ((a) ci-dessus), on s'aperçoit que « se sentir » est un semi-auxiliaire d'aspect qui peut très bien être appelé l'aspect inchoatif/duratif.

Il existe un problème cependant, puisque comme c'est dit dans l'article,

*« En grammaire française, un semi-auxiliaire est un verbe conjugué qui, combiné avec un infinitif non complément de ce verbe, **forme une périphrase**. »*,

l'ensemble « se sentait saisir » est un seul verbe dont le sujet est « Cosette » et donc il faut que Cosette ait saisi quelque chose et non pas que Cosette ait été saisie par quelque chose; il y a donc une faute de la part de l'auteur. Il aurait dû écrire « se sentait saisie ».

La seconde phrase est aussi en erreur.

(Tout à coup il se sentit saisi par le bras.)

Comment: Err ? : *"La seconde phrase est aussi en erreur*" ??? Vous voulez dire que VH s'est gaufré ? J'en ai failli frémir...

Comment: Ça n'a rien à voir avec les semi-auxiliaires mais avec les verbes de perception. En plus des liens donnés par @jlliagre voir aussi sur [termiumplus](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_v&page=9WDmlJxvoQbA.html). Le choix fait par Hugo est stylistique.  Cosette se sentait saisir ... l'emploi de la forme active personnifie la forêt, ce qui la rend plus terrifiante, les sentiments de Cosette sont décrits ensuite.

Comment: De même pour l'extrait pour l'extrait des travailleurs de la mer où la pieuvre et mise en action pour montrer la surprise totale du pêcheur.

Comment: @aCOSwt Je crois sincèrement qu'il y a derrière cette habitude (puisque voilà deux cas) une misconception de sa part.

Comment: Ce n'est pas spécifique à Hugo. C'est un procédé stylistique courant et qui s'apprend au lycée en cours de français. Par contre il est normal qu'un non francophone soit surpris la première fois qu'il le rencontre.

Comment: @Laure Il n'y a rien de stylistique dans les phrases suivantes et dans toutes il est nécessaire que le sujet fasse l'action de ce verbe. • Je me suis senti partir. •  Il se sentait redevenir un enfant. • La mère se sentait tuer la foi en elle. • Il se sentait mâcher son chewing-gum avec délice.

Comment: *Une misconception* ?? Vous voulez dire que Hugo n'a pas dit ce qu'il voulait dire ?

Comment: @aCOSwt Non, je veux dire dire, bien que ce soit surprenant, qu'il aurait assimilé une forme impropre pour « se sentir +part. passé », la signification passive étant bien ce qu'il avait en tête.

Comment: Les phrases que tu proposes n'ont rien à voir avec la construction de la phrase sur laquelle interroge la question.  Dans tes phrases il n'y a un sujet qui fait une action. ( Même la mère c'est elle qui tue la foi). Dans la phrase de la question posée il y a une action faite par un agent extérieur sur un autre personnage qui subit les conséquences de cette action.

Comment: @Laure Bien sûr, elle est impropre selon le point de vue que je soutiens, tant que je le soutiens ; il faut bien y référer. Selon les articles il faudrait que « saisir » soit complément d'objet donc ; « saisir » est pronominalisable ?  (Cosette se **le** sentait)

Comment: Vu que tu ne te réfères aux articles traitant du sujet (à savoir les verbes de perception) sûr que tu ne peux que te tromper. Et j'arrête là.

Comment: @Laure Non, les articles ou plutôt l'article est essentiellement l'article que je cite dans la Wikipédia et qui traite non pas des verbes perceptifs mais des verbes semi-auxiliaires et dont l'analyse explique que l'on distingue ces verbes parce que le verbe qui suit ne peut pas être un complément d'objet, ce qui semble bien être le cas dans la présente question.

Comment: "une misconception de sa part" ? Voir https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/34628/emploi-du-mot-misconception.

Comment: @Dimitris Très bonne remarque, merci. Je fais une petite modification : « misconception ».